# How to complete the fitch-style proof to get the desired conclusion?

Tags: logic, fitch-proofs

With this one you can use Taut Con (to implement MT, DS, DeM, if needed).  Your main strategy is conditional proof/ →-Intro so you'll need a subproof.

premise 1: P → (Q → R)
premise 2: P → (Q ∨ S)
premise 3: P → ¬R
prove: P → S

I tried this:

1. P → (Q → R)        Premise
2. P → (Q ∨ S)        Premise
3. P → ¬R             Premise
4. Assume P            Assumption
5. Assume Q          Assumption
6. ```
    P → R           → Elimination (1)
   ```
7. ```
    R               → Elimination (4, 6)
   ```
8. ```
    ¬R              → Elimination (3)
   ```
9. Q → ¬R           → Introduction (5-8)
10. Assume S          Assumption
11. ```
    Q ∨ S          → Elimination (2)
    ```
12. ```
    ¬R             → Elimination (9, 10)
    ```
13. S                ∨ Elimination (11)
14. P → S              → Introduction (4-13)

I was expecting it all to be true but it was not.